# How to set date to NULL in ODBC

Tags: odbc, pervasive-sql, xojo

I am using XOJO and pervasiveDB via ODBC. 
There is a form that I need to update and on that form I have a date field that can be deleted on the form. When the date is deleted on the form, I need it deleted in the DB as well.

I am using ODBC, and can't do it for some reason. I have tried sending NULL, nil, 0000-00-00 and it is simply not doing it.

I have even tried not to send it if the date is deleted hoping for the best, but it will simply not go away.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  From a Pervasive perspective, you can set a date to null if the field allows it. If it doesn't, you would have to specify a valid data 0000-01-01 to 9999-12-31.

Answer (score 1):

I think I resolved this issue. This is the solution:

The only working solution, after trying many different things.

```
  dim inTYP as string = "6010-03"


SQLupdateBLIN = "update BLIN set inDAT=NULL  WHERE inTYP= '" + inTYP +"'"
```

If I send the inDAT in following format (send it as variable), then it is not working (no error, just does not work):

dim inDAT as string = "NULL"

It seems ODBC is not liking variables that have value set to null.

Answer (score 0):

Using direct SQL will definitely work.

If you are using a RecordSet, then you want to set the column to NULL using syntax like this:

```
MyRecordSet.Field("inDAT").Value = Nil
```

But whether this works is completely dependent on the ODBC driver.